# segment:offset in a constant

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I'm trying to learn assembly. I've written this short real mode function that works as I want to.

```
getndrives:
        push    bx
        push    es
        push    si
            mov     bx,0040h
            mov     es,bx
            mov     si,0075h
            mov     al,byte [es:si]
        pop     si
        pop     es
        pop     bx
    ret
```

I would like to have the segment:offset in a constant instead and eliminate the need to push/pop es+si. Something like

```
biosmem EQU 0040h:0075h
mov al,[biosmem]
```

above code compiles but does not return the intended result.

Comment: Please post answers as *answers*, not as edits to the question.  (i.e. copy your update to an answer and rollback the question.)  Also, have a look at my answer for a suggestion that avoids one pair of push/pop if you don't mind clobbering AH and returning the result zero-extended into AX.  You can put segment values into non-"pointer" registers like AX.

Comment: Are you writing a DOS COM program or bootloader?

Comment: If you're going to preserve the segment register anyway, then better use the `DS` segment register. That way you'll avoid the extra code byte of the segment override prefix on `mov al,byte [es:si]`. => `mov al, [si]`

Comment: @MichaelPetch a petite kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 doesn't have a way to load from an immediate-constant far-pointer in one instruction.  There's a far `jmp ptr16:16` that can set `cs:ip` to a 32-bit immediate, but for loads I don't see any option that doesn't use a segment register.

---

[NASM docs suggest](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.4.2) that it is/was typical in 16-bit calling conventions for `DS` to be call-preserved, but that `ES` could be considered call-clobbered for exactly the reason you want (in memory models that don't keep everything in a single segment).

So you could consider using a calling convention for this function that allows it to clobber `ES`.  (Or `FS` or `GS` if your code only needs to run on 386 or later.)

You can also save instructions by reusing the same register for the segment.  You could have used `si` both times instead of `bx`, because you're done with `bx` as soon as you set `es`.

```
getndrives:
 ;; return in AL (zero-extended to AX; the upper byte of 0040h happens to be 0)
 ;; clobbers: AH, ES
    mov     ax, 0x0040
    mov     es, ax
    mov     al, [es:0x0475]
    ret
```

As a bonus, you're loading into AL so it can use the special [`moffs` encoding of `mov`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/MOV.html) that skips the ModR/M byte so it's just (ES segment override prefix) + `A0 75 04`.

You can of course still push/pop `es` and/or `ax` around this if you want, but this is obviously clunkier.  And if you're going to save/restore a segment register, @Fifoernik points out it might as well be DS to save a prefix on the `mov` (unless you have any interrupt handlers that assume DS stays constant).

```
getndrives:
 ;; return in AL (zero-extended to AX; the upper byte of 0040h happens to be 0)
 ;; clobbers: AH,  or nothing if you uncomment the push/pop of AX
    push    es
    ;push    ax                 ; you might as well use a reg other than AX to simplify this, if you do want to preserve AH, too.  And also for performance on CPUs that don't rename low8 partial regs separately, so mov al,[mem] has a dependency on the pop.
      mov     ax, 0x0040
      mov     es, ax            ; or use DS if you don't need it in any interrupt handler
    ;pop     ax
      mov     al, [es:0x0475]
    pop     es
    ret
```

If you only care about 186 and newer, `push 0040h` / `pop es` would avoid clobbering AH.  (8086 doesn't have `push imm8/imm16`).

---

**In your case, you can probably avoid modifying a segment register in the first place**.  Notice that `0040h:0075h` is a linear address of `0475h`, which you can access with just an offset from any `DS` value from `0` to `47h`.  (In real mode, `linear = (segment << 4) + offset`, i.e. left-shift by one hex digit).

With DS=0, you can still access your boot-sector code/data ([according to this PC memory map](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html), loaded at `07C0:0`, aka `0:7C00`), and anywhere else in the low 64kiB of memory.

I don't actually write 16-bit code, so I'm not sure exactly how you'd tell NASM that you're going to set `DS=0` and then have it generate offsets accordingly.  But hopefully that's possible.

As a bonus, it saves code size: `xor ax,ax` is smaller than `mov ax, imm16`.  But I guess if you were optimizing for code size, you'd `push 0` / `pop ds`.  (But 8086 doesn't have `push imm`, that came later).  And I guess if you want stack pointers to be compatible with other pointers, you'd need to `mov ss, ax` / `mov sp, whatever` so that's more code.

But anyway, then your function would look like this.

```
getndrives:
 ;; return in AL
 ;; requires/assumes: DS=0
    mov     al, [0x0475]
    ret
```

At this point it's silly to make it a function.  Make it a macro, or better, or `%define BIOS_BDA_ndrives 0x0475` so you can do stuff like `add dl, [BIOS_BDA_ndrives]`.  Or possibly `%define BIOS_BDA_ndrives byte [0x0475]` to get build-time type checking, e.g. `mov ax, BIOS_BDA_ndrives` would then fail to assemble with an operand-size mismatch.

Comment: "As a bonus" The example that does `push es` / `pop es` would benefit from using `DS` instead. No need for the segment override prefix!

Comment: @Fifoernik: Nice idea.  Would it be common to assume DS had a certain value in an interrupt handler, though?

Comment: @Fifoernik: On a CPU with out-of-order execution, `pop ds` would be an input dependency for future loads/stores using DS (i.e. almost everything except the stack).  But `pop es` could still be executing in parallel with future DS:  loads/stores.  e.g. on Conroe/Merom, `pop sr` is 10 uops, one per 17 cycle throughput, so there's easily room for out-of-order execution.  (IDK if it's faster in real mode vs. protected, though.  [Agner maybe only timed in compat / long modes](http://agner.org/optimize/).)

Answer (score 1):

The segment part of an address always uses a segment register. You can use a constant for the offset.

Comment: So `mov al, [es:my_offset]` and changing `mov bx,0040h` to `mov bx,my_segment` is how I would best avoid hard coding the memory address if I understand you correctly?